# Boost unable to verify IPv6 with square brackets

Tags: c++

I'm using Boost's `boost::asio::ip::address::from_string` to validate IPs and it turns out it can't validate IPv6 if it's enclosed in square brackets. Not sure if this is intentional, but I wonder if there is a way to make it works? Perhaps some other method within boost?

```
boost::system::error_code invalid;
boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("[2607:f8b0:4008:80d::2004]", invalid);

if (invalid)
{
    std::cout << "DEBUG: Invalid IP " << invalid << "\n";
}
```

When it runs, it prints 22 as an error code.

I welcome any other solutions if this is not possible to do with Boost.

Comment: Square brackets are not standard, as described in RFC 4291. I think you'll need a custom parser.

Comment: @freakish But every browser sends IPv6 in that form.

Comment: A browser uses square brackets inside uris. And yes, inside a uri a square bracket is well defined in the standard. But what you have is not uri. Well, it may be treated as uri without scheme. Either way you need a different parser.

Comment: @freakish HTTP requests enclose IPv6 in this form inside the host header.  I know a custom parser but it seems a bit overkill, eg it's very huge!

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly is huge? What does it even mean "huge"? What is an overkill? Uri parsing is not a rocket science. Plus, you need it, so...

Comment: @freakish Boost is portable and I avoid external dependencies much as possible unless it's a single header-only library. That's my personal preference. Maybe it will change with C++20 modules.

Comment: Your personal preference is to write any code you can't find in boost by yourself? Well, its your choice. So write your own parser. As I said: its not really hard.

Comment: @jeffbRTC and what is the problem to check if the string is enclosed within `[` and `]`,  and if so remove it and then check if it is a valid ipv6? That are not more than a few lines of code that can be written in one function.  And if you come up with a better solution be replaced within that single function.

Comment: @freakish The reason I believe Boost capable of this is because of ASIO. ASIO has HTTP capabilities so they should have written something to support this.  But if this is not, I'm fine.

Comment: @t.niese Probably because of extra overhead?

Comment: @t.niese unlikely to be that easy. OP is dealing with `host` header.

Comment: @jeffbRTC what overhead? You cannot retrieve information without work. But is parsing uri an amount of work you should worry about? Is it comparable for example to network i/o? Extremely unlikely.

Comment: @freakish Host header is parsed, the port is stripped out

Comment: @freakish Well, you end up looping two times  (One to remove these chars and another to validate itself) and that's costly.

Comment: @jeffbRTC Is it really costly to analyze a short string twice? Have you measured it? Because I bet $100 that you won't even notice a difference with and without. Unless you have 1980' computer. Also: make the code correct first, optimize afterwards if necessary.

Comment: @freakish Even sub-microsecond latency matters to me. But I end up with that [ and ] thing, see my answer below...

Comment: @jeffbRTC I think you've misunderstood what "parser" means. What you gave in your answer is an example of a parser. Whether it is correct, efficient and errorproof is another story.

Comment: @jeffbRTC also, you loop twice, even 3 times, in your code anyway. Once for `.pop_back()`, once for `.erase()` (both require copy of most of the string), and once for boost's `from_string`. This tells me that yours "even sub-microsecond latency matters to me" is just random, meaningless statement.

Comment: @freakish I'm dead serious. I will completely remove this code to all in one efficient one when I see the page loaded. And, I use Folly not STL  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution.

Basically, We check if the string has `[` or `]` then erase it else keep it as it's.

```
int main()
{
    std::string str("[2607:f8b0:4008:80d::2004]");

    if(str.front() == '[' && str.back() == ']') {
      str.pop_back();
      str.erase(str.begin());
    }

    boost::system::error_code invalid;
    boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(str, invalid);

    if (invalid)
    {
      std::cout << "DEBUG: Invalid IP " << invalid << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you assume that the data is not valid for some reason, removing all `[` and `]` might not be a good idea (If the string e.g. is something like `[2607:f8[[[][]]b0:4008:80d::2004]`). It would be better to just check the string starts with `[` and ends with `]`, and remove them in that case.

Comment: Why check the entire string?  If you know the square brackets are and the ends just check `*str.begin()` and `*str.rbegin()`.

Comment: @t.niese I have two front end parsers that handle this

Comment: What do you mean by `front end parser`?  If you parse it twice in the same app this seems a waste of performance, and if you mean with `front end parser` something that is not on your server then this is nice to have but you must never trust the data you receive over network.

Comment: @t.niese llhttp and another URI parsing library (Which splits URIs to diff parts) and they handle this kind of bogus URIs

Comment: @t.niese But you can see on my updated answer, I now check if string starts by [ and end by ]

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. I just wanted to emphasize that any validations that are made outside of your application that receives the data (like https headers, …), should be treated as if they didn't happen outside of the application, and still need to be done in the application itself. If you leave this checks out in the best case are just prone to crashes, in the worst case you have a possible attack vector.